# How to count distinct Id based on rolling timestamp with group by in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, rolling-computation

| Eid | timestamp | Mid | timestamp_6before | ACiddate | ACid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 7/10/2021 | A | 1/10/2021 | 7/15/2021 | 123 |
| bcd | 8/10/2021 | A | 2/10/2021 | 7/6/2021 | 456 |
| def | 6/10/2021 | A | 12/10/2021 | 3/1/2021 | 789 |

I am trying to count the distinct ACid by Mid, but with rolling 6 months of data based on timestamp.

For example, for the 1st row of timestamp, the rolling 6 months date range is 1/10/2021 to 7/10/2021. I should count the distinct ACid in this time period, thus the ACid on 7/6/2021 and 3/1/2021 (ACiddate) are included. Similarly for other rows.
The output should be like following:

| Eid | timestamp | Mid | timestamp_6before | ACid_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 7/10/2021 | A | 1/10/2021 | 2 |
| bcd | 8/10/2021 | A | 2/10/2021 | 3 |
| def | 6/10/2021 | A | 12/10/2021 | 1 |

With a single `GROUP BY Mid` the output count all the ACid by Mid. Is there a solution to count based on each timestamp (date range)?

Comment: Don't forget to tell us what database this is in; SQL is a standard, not an implementation

Answer (score 0):

One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where t2.ACiddate <= t.ACiddate and
              t2.ACiddate >= t.timestamp_6before
       ) as ACid_count
from t;
```